# Check the exact Git command run by IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'ld like to know if there is a way to see the exact Git commands run by IntelliJ.

Like when I do an `Update Project`, with the rebase and stash options.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using rubymine, if it's the same you should get a `tool window` for version control with all the command that were run and the output.

tools window = The small panels on the side and bottom, like `project view`, `changes`, `to do` etc.

To open it ( if it's not already open ) try `View => Tool Windows => Version Control`.

Answer (score 0):

Since IntelliJ Idea GIT plugin uses command line git utility, you may temporarily replace it with a simple shell wrapper which would log every invocation into a file (assuming that the real `git` binary is saved as `/usr/bin/git.bin` :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Invoked git $@" >>/tmp/git.log
exec /usr/bin/git.bin "$@"
```

Also you may simply read a good GIT documentation, e.g. http://git-scm.com/documentation